# Cosmic mind - how to change title bar button's tint color

Tags: ios, swift, material-ui, tintcolor, cosmicmind

```
import UIKit
import Material

class MyVC: UITableViewController {
    fileprivate var deleteButton: IconButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareDeleteButton()

        navigationItem.rightViews = [deleteButton]
    }
    // other delegates of UITableView
}

extension MyVC {
    fileprivate func prepareDeleteButton() {
        deleteButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "Trash"))
        deleteButton.tintColor = Color.red.base
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc
    fileprivate func doSomething() {
        print("delete accessory")
    }
}
```

Note that `MyVC` is pushed from another `ViewController`.

In `MyVC`, I want my trash can icon to be at the upper right corner of the screen, which is `navigationItem.rightViews = [deleteButton]`, and to have red base color `deleteButton.tintColor = Color.red.base`.

But it does not work in the code above, the trash can is still black. How can I change its tint color?

It seems that my trash icon is a little bigger then other Cosmic Mind icons at the same `rightViews` although it has the same size as Cosmic Mind icons (24x24 @1x). Is it true? How to make it a little smaller?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are not using the correct rendering mode. Try this:

```
deleteButton = IconButton(image: UIImage(named: "Trash")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
```

All the best!

Comment: Another trick is to set in `xcassets` by selecting that image, then choosing `Template Image` in `Render As` of `Attributes Inspector`. Thanks for the hint